# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. With Entity Framwork and stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, delete-row, removeall

I have a problem to make the delete action, well, I'm not really eliminating I'm just changing the status.

I'm using a stored procedure to deleted or change status

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_Empresa] 
    @CveEmpresaPK int = NULL,
    @Estatus bit = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @Estatus = 0
    begin
        update CatEmpresas 
        set Estatus = 'False'
        where CveEmpresaPK = @CveEmpresaPK
    end
    else
    begin
        update CatEmpresas 
        set Estatus = 'True'
        where CveEmpresaPK = @CveEmpresaPK
    end
END
```

I add my SP to my table in "assignment stored procedure"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7WEt.png)

and my stored procedure is mapping in my table of Entity Framework

[image]

The method in C# is (Class BaseRepository.cs):

```
public void Detele(TEntity entity)
{
        try
        {
            using (_context)
            {
                _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);

                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
}
```

I using only two data

My repository when call BaseRepository.cs:

```
 public class CatEmpresas_Repositorio : Base.BaseRepository<CatEmpresa>, Interfaces.ICatEmpresas
{
    private DBControlCalidadEntities _context = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Iniciamos una instancia con una clase generica para Create, Update y Detele
    /// </summary>
    public CatEmpresas_Repositorio()
        : base(new DBControlCalidadEntities())
    {
    }
```

[image]

and my Entitie :

```
namespace SistemaControl_Entidades {

 public partial class CatEmpresa
{
    public CatEmpresa()
    {
        this.CatPersonals = new HashSet<CatPersonal>();
        this.Cve1NivelDepto = new HashSet<Cve1NivelDepto>();
    }

---->public int CveEmpresaPK { get; set; }
    public string NombreEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string RFC { get; set; }
    public string TipoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Colonia { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CveEstadoFK { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CveMpioFK { get; set; }
  ----->public Nullable<bool> Estatus { get; set; }......
```

Help me please, what happens?

Comment: your Set<TEntity> contains all those entities that are in your context. Though derived of IQueryable<T>, it is not meant to call Remove directly on this Set (I doubt EF can translate this into an Retrieve+Delete call). Try gathering the data in your context and then set the EntityState to deleted. Also, a using() statement with a global context might lead you into errors (since Dispose() is called upon leaving the block).

Comment: Where in your code you call your Delete_Empresa SP? I don't see it. Also, are you using Entity Framework Code first?

Comment: Please show how you mapped the sproc to the Delete action. I think the second parameter `@Estatus` doesn't work well here.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro `DbSet.Remove` is designed to do exactly that: remove entities so EF will delete them by `SaveChanges`.

Comment: well, 1.- It's DataBase First in EF, and my table I add the SP action, I add the functions Create, Update and Delete, these SP using as entities, the entities generated of my tables.

Comment: add the SP to my model of my ADO, then I assigned the SP to my table, well I made a CRUD with EF and SP, example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx
understand??

Comment: I think, in Create and Update, make it's function respectively, but in the function Delete also only uses two fields, the SP only updates and not delete, has something to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want and also avoid the need to retrieve all the entities before marking for them for "exclusion" by invoking the SP directly from your context:

```
using (_context)
{
    string stpSQL = @"EXEC [dbo].[Delete_Empresa] @CveEmpresaPK, @Estatus";

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.EnsureTransaction, stpSQL,
        new SqlParameter("@CveEmpresaPK", entity.CveEmpresaPK),
        new SqlParameter("@Estatus", entity.Estatus));
}
```

Comment: I'm using the entities of my table, the SP is mapping in the model of my EF with the table as delete function, the same way Create and Update (CRUD with EF and SP) I was able to create and update but I can not delete